# SQL: CASE issue, convert date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

below is a part of my SQL query, only part becasue it is quite long.

The problem is that when I add CASE to my select statement it gives me an error.
NSO Review column contains date. However not for all rows date is available and query then puts '1900-01-01' instead. I want  to replace this with NO and if there is any other value then put YES. Could you please help

```
SELECT 'NSO Review' = ISNULL(tblTaskEventsHistory.TimeIn,''),
        CASE CAST(tblTaskEventsHistory.TimeIn AS varchar(102))
        WHEN '1900' THEN  'NO'
        ELSE 'YES'
        END,    
        'Business Group' = ISNULL(MetadataBG.Value,''),
        'CTN' = ISNULL(MetadataCT.Value,''),
```

**ERROR**

> Msg 1038, Level 15, State 5, Line 277
>   An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using and the error message you got is not in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should , as mentioned before, use DateTime functions.
To compare some parts of the date, there is the function DATEPART 
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).

Then you could try this one :

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN DATEPART(yy, tblTaskEventsHistory.TimeIn) = 1900 THEN 'NO' 
ELSE 'YES' 
END AS Status;
```

Hope it 'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the error message: "Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed" and "verify each column has a name":

```
SELECT NSO_Review = ISNULL(tblTaskEventsHistory.TimeIn,''),
       TimeIn = CASE CAST(tblTaskEventsHistory.TimeIn AS varchar(102))
        WHEN '1900' THEN  'NO'
        ELSE 'YES'
        END,
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that its SELECT INTO.

Comment: Its is workig like below but I get all YESes
SELECT 'NSO Review' = ISNULL(tblTaskEventsHistory.TimeIn,''),
  CASE  tblTaskEventsHistory.TimeIn 
  WHEN '1900' THEN  'NO'
  ELSE 'YES'
  END AS NSORequest,

Answer (score 0):

You have missed name of the column for your case statement.